# Maven class loader doesn't find any resources

Tags: java, maven, classloader

When using maven to package a jar (unsure if it's a maven issue) the java ClassLoader can't find any resources.

Jar structure -

[image]

Value of `test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("")` (or any other existing directory) is empty. No folders or files or found.

Maven Build Script:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>9</source>
          <target>9</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation=
                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>org.swordofsouls.discord.chatexporter.test</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Tried using different ClassLoaders.

Value of `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` is null.

Value of `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` is null.

Comment: Where have you put your resources? Please show the project layout.

Comment: @khmarbaise resources are in the default resource folder, "Html" is a folder placed in the resources folder which contains the files I want to access

Comment: Than you have to use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Html/...")` to access resources...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use
`/` instead of `File.separator`